# How to determine if a two dimensional list is "rectangular"

Tags: python, list

Right now I'm trying to get my program to take a two dimensional list as an input and return either true or false depending on whether or not it is "rectangular" (eg. [[2,3],[1,5],[6,9]] is rectangular whereas [[2,3],[1,8,6]] is not.) So far I've come up with this:

```
def rectangular(List):
    n = List
    for i in n:
        if len(i) != len(n[0]):
            return False
        elif len(i) == len(n[0]):
            i
```

I can't seem to figure out how to create a "true" case. Using the elif above I'm able to cycle through the list but if i were to add a return true portion it stops as soon as that is the case. Would a while loop work better in this case? All help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The definition of what makes a 2D list rectangular is unclear. However, in terms of programming itself, set a flag to True before the loop, and check for all conditions that would make it NOT rectangular inside the loop. If determined to be not rectangular, set the flag to False and break. At the end of the loop, return the flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get to the end without finding a false case, then you know it's true, right? There aren't any other possibilities.

So, you can just remove the `elif` entirely, and just add a `return True` at the end:

```
def rectangular(List):
    n = List
    for i in n:
        if len(i) != len(n[0]):
            return False
    return True
```

As a side note, your `elif` that has exactly the opposite condition as the `if` is better written as just `else:`. That way, there's no chance of you getting the opposite condition wrong, no need for your readers to figure out that it's the opposite, etc.

Also, there's no reason to take the argument as `List`, then bind the same value to `n` and use that. Why not just take `n` in the first place?

```
def rectangular(n):
    for i in n:
        if len(i) != len(n[0]):
            return False
    return True
```

---

You can make this more concise, and maybe more Pythonic, by replacing the `for` statement with a generator expression and the `all` function:

```
def rectangular(n):
    return all(len(i) == len(n[0]) for i in n)
```

But really, this isn't much different from what you already have. You *should* learn how this works, but if you don't understand it yet, there's no problem doing it the more verbose way.

---

If you want to get clever:

```
def rectangular(n):
    lengths = {len(i) for i in n}
    return len(lengths) == 1
```

We're making a set of all of the lengths. Sets don't have duplicates, so this is a set of all of the *distinct* lengths. If there's only 1 distinct length, that means all of the lengths are the same.

However, note that for an empty list, this will return `False` (because there are *0* lengths, not 1), while the other two will return `True` (because a condition is vacuously true for all values if there are no values to test). I'm not sure which one you want, but it should be relatively easy to figure out how to change whichever one you choose to do the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function with a generator:

```
def rectangular(lst):
    first_len = len(lst[0])
    # I used lst[1:] to skip the 0th element
    return all(len(x) == first_len for x in lst[1:])
```

The `all` function returns `True` if all elements of an iterable are `True`, and `False` otherwise.

It's good that you didn't call your variable `list`, but capitalized names usually represent a class in Python, so `lst` is a better choice than `List`.

---

**NOTE**: I made the assumption that "rectangular" means each sublist is the same length.  If in reality each sublist should be (say) 2 elements long, just replace `first_len` with the literal `2` and remove the `[1:]` on `lst[1:]`.  You may also want to add some exception handling in case you pass a list with only one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that the lengths of all elements of the list are the same length. Or in Python:

```
all(map(lambda m: len(m) == len(x[0]), x))
```

Where `x` is what you want to check.

The only problem with this solution is that the if the list looks like `[ [1,2], [1,[1,2]], 'ab' ]`, it is still going to return `True`. So you additionally need to do some type checking.

Comment: Why use `map` instead of a comprehension here?

Comment: No reason. Either is fine and mostly interchangable.

Comment: Semantically, sure, the only difference is that this will be slightly slower… but as far as readability goes, an expression is a lot easier to understand than an expression wrapped in a lambda.

Comment: Well, if the whole expression is just a function call with the loop variable as the only argument, a comprehension can be _less_ readable—think `map(int, spam)` vs. `(int(x) for x in spam)`. Which I think is part of the reason Guido didn't deprecate `map` and `filter` once comprehensions were added.